# jQuery - How to reset form input from outside of iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

With the iFrame embedded in, my HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <iframe ...>
        <html>
            // html content inside iframe:
            <head>...</head>
            <body>
                <input class="in-iframe" type="text" />
            <body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</form>
```

With jQuery, doing this:

```
$("form").trigger("reset")
```

only resets the input outside of the iFrame, not one on the inside.

How do I reset the input inside the iFrame?

Comment: You would need to include that code snippet within the iframe. Think of it as a completely separate page within your outer page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe